# When should you balance a time series dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, class-imbalance

I'm training a machine learning algorithm to classify up/down trends in a time series and I'm using an imbalanced feature set. It seems necessary to balance the data since the algorithm could learn a bias towards a particular trend, but this comes at the cost of a non-representative dataset. Should I balance my data? And if so, is random undersampling the right method?

Comment: Which types of models do you use? some models are less sensitive to imbalanced datasets

Comment: @Omri374: I'm testing an LSTM network, SVM, and Random Forest classifier.

Comment: For SVMs and Random Forests, are you using a sliding window to create samples? If yes, you can then perform sampling on the created windows

Comment: For LSTMs, you could tweak the loss function. see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197273/class-balancing-in-deep-neural-network and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155655/loss-function-for-class-imbalanced-binary-classifier-in-tensor-flow

Comment: You might want to read [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/96e7/a6aec040f6674562a73bbdb4cda9ab0c0d4b.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the `Loss function` of the algorithm, It will be very helpful and as a result you don't need to down sample your data. There are many useful metrics which were introduced for evaluating the performance of classification methods for imbalanced data-sets. Some of them are **[Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)**, **[CEN](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.708.1668&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**, **[MCEN](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-94120-2_8)**, **[MCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)**, and **[DP](https://eva.fing.edu.uy/pluginfile.php/69453/mod_resource/content/1/7633-10048-1-PB.pdf)**.

Disclaimer:

If you use python, **[PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm)** module can help you to find out these metrics.

Here is a simple code to get the recommended parameters from this module:

```
>>> from pycm import *

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(matrix={"Class1": {"Class1": 1, "Class2":2}, "Class2": {"Class1": 0, "Class2": 5}})  

>>> print(cm.recommended_list)
["Kappa", "SOA1(Landis & Koch)", "SOA2(Fleiss)", "SOA3(Altman)", "SOA4(Cicchetti)", "CEN", "MCEN", "MCC", "J", "Overall J", "Overall MCC", "Overall CEN", "Overall MCEN", "AUC", "AUCI", "G", "DP", "DPI", "GI"]
```

After that, each of these parameters you want to use as the loss function can be used as follows:

```
>>> y_pred = model.predict      #the prediction of the implemented model

>>> y_actu = data.target        #data labels

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred)

>>> loss = cm.Kappa             #or any other parameter (Example: cm.SOA1)
```